# DFS exploration of nodes vs A*

Tags: search, dijkstra, depth-first-search, a-star

I'm trying to implement a search for a personal project in which the exploration of the nodes are relatively expensive. I was hesitant between using DFS(Dijkstra's Forward Search) or A*.

My question is, will there be a case where A* explores more nodes than DFS?

Comment: Can you give a reference to Dijkstra's Forward Search? DFS usually means "Depth First Search".

Answer (score 2):

**Dijkstra's** original algorithm does not use a min-priority queue and runs in time **|V|^2**  (where |V|  is the number of nodes). The implementation based on a min-priority queue implemented by a Fibonacci heap and running in **O(|E|+|V|\log |V|)**  (where |E| is the number of edges) is due to (Fredman & Tarjan 1984). This is asymptotically the fastest known single-source shortest-path algorithm for arbitrary directed graphs with unbounded non-negative weights. However, specialized cases (such as bounded/integer weights, directed acyclic graphs etc) can indeed be improved further.

The time complexity of **A*** depends on the heuristic. In the worst case of an unbounded search space, the number of nodes expanded is exponential in the depth of the solution (the shortest path) d: **O(b^d)**, where b is the branching factor (the average number of successors per state).This assumes that a goal state exists at all, and is reachable from the start state; if it is not, and the state space is infinite, the algorithm will not terminate.

The **A* algorithm** is a generalization of Dijkstra's algorithm that **cuts down on the size of the subgraph that must be explored, if additional information is available** that provides a lower bound on the "distance" to the target. This approach can be viewed from the perspective of linear programming: there is a natural linear program for computing shortest paths, and solutions to its dual linear program are feasible if and only if they form a consistent heuristic (speaking roughly, since the sign conventions differ from place to place in the literature). This feasible dual / consistent heuristic defines a non-negative reduced cost and A* is essentially running Dijkstra's algorithm with these reduced costs. If the dual satisfies the weaker condition of admissibility, then A* is instead more akin to the Bellman–Ford algorithm.
**Worst case performance     O(|E|)=O(b^{d})**
and
**Worst case space complexity  O(|V|)=O(b^{d})**

Dijkstra's algorithm can be viewed as a special case of A* where h(x)=0 for all x.
It should be noted, however, that **Dijkstra's algorithm can be implemented more efficiently** without including a h(x) value at each node.